# Memory deallocation c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I obviously misunderstood something using `delete`.
Why is this program filling up my memory?

```
void f(int* x){
    x = new int[42];
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        int* x;
        f(x);
        delete[] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I free the memory I allocated in `f` from inside the `main` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not actually modifying the `x` variable in the outer function.
To do that, you have either to rely on the returned value of `f`:

```
int* f(){
    return new int[42];
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        int* x = f();
        delete[] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or to pass the variable `x` by reference:

```
void f(int*& x){
    x = new int[42];
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        int* x;
        f(x);
        delete[] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or to use a pointer to pointer as an argument to `f`:

```
void f(int** x){
    *x = new int[42];
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        int* x;
        f(&x);
        delete[] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

There are memory leaks in the function

```
void f(int* x){
    x = new int[42];
}
```

You allocate memory but never free it. Function parameters are local variables of the function. The function deals with a copy of the original pointer. Any changes of the copy do not influence on the original argument.

And mpreover the program has undefined behaviour because pointer `x` is not initialized.

```
int main(){
    while(true){
        int* x;
        ^^^^^^
        f(x);
        delete[] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need to pass the original pointer by reference. So the function should be defined like

```
void f(int* &x){
    x = new int[42];
}
```

and called like

```
f(x);
```

or defined like

```
void f(int* *x){
    *x = new int[42];
}
```

and called like

```
f( &x );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameter by reference. You're passing it by value.

Answer (score -1):

So what you might want to do is consider constructing a functor/class/struct that uses RAII...

By this I mean how the standard library handles a lot of allocations.

```
struct A {
A(){/*allocate mem*/}
~A(){/*deallocate mem*/}
}
```

For your particular function,

```
void f(int** x);
```

is most likely the signature you want. This will allow you to modify the array through the pointer to it. Though... I still recommend not doing this... the reason is what about if you decide to allocate a bunch of arrays? Does the main method take responsibility for deallocating memory?